# Setting the placeholder text color / hiding the cancel Button using swift on iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a UiSearchbar within my Navigation Bar. The SearchBar style is minimal. I am on iOS 8, using a SearchController (no SearchDisplayController) and Swift.

1. I would like to set the placeholder and the icon color to white. Is this possible? All that I've found so far seems to be outdated or the author is not sure whether this code will be approved by Apple.
2. I would like to get rid of the cancel Button, but when I try this:
   `searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false`
   within the viewDidLoad, the cancel button still shows up.

I must say, I am creating the searchBar programmatically..

Answer (score 6):

For your first problem, you could access the `UITextField` of your `UISearchbar` and edit the placeholder color:

```
var textfield:UITextField = searchBar.valueForKey("searchField") as UITextField

//Set the foregroundcolor of the placeholder
var attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "your placeholdertext", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()])

textfield.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString
```

Then to also set the glass-color you have to access the `leftView` of your `UITextField`:

```
//Get the glass icon
var iconView:UIImageView = textfield.leftView as UIImageView
//Make the icon to a template which you can edit
iconView.image = iconView.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
//Set the color of the icon
iconView.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

To hide the cancel-button in your `UISearchbar` you can use the `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` delegate method and hide it. Just make sure to add the `UISearchBarDelegate` first and set the delegate to your searchbar:

```
 class YourviewController:UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        searchbar.delegate = self
    }

    func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, unfortunately, the last bit of code doesn't have any effect. The cancel button still shows up. I've double test that the searchBarShouldBeginEditing function will be called.. Anyway, Thanks for your amazing help.

Is changing the color of the uisearchfield using the above code ok for apple? I don't want my app to be rejected because of this ;)

Comment: It should be absolutely ok. But the code for the cancel button should work. Have you added the delegate to "self" of your searchbar?

Comment: As I said, the method is called.. I already had this: searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

Comment: In Swift 3 I used     searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Text"